# OpenCart .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, opencart

Using [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) how would I use a 301 redirect to add `www.` to the domain

`.htaccess` content:

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#OPENCART REWRITES START
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
#OPENCART REWRITES END

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.mysite\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that 302 redirects are working

Comment: Are you sure it's 302 instead of 301? Ran that .htaccess and it works okay with 301,

Comment: Unfortunately I am sure.

Comment: Could you perhaps show the part of your logs that shows it going 302?

Comment: See this answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all that you are wanting to do is this inside of your Apache config file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.net/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I am keeping this as standard for non-www to www and force https both. No further change required.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```