# Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

but whenever I access a file on my root like `http://example.com/robots.txt` it will redirect to `http://www.example.comrobots.txt/`.

How can I correct this so that it will redirect correctly to `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`?

Answer (score 455, accepted):

Change your configuration to this (add a slash):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or the solution outlined below (proposed by [@absiddiqueLive](//stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess/22299685#22299685)) will work for any domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you need to support http and https and preserve the protocol choice try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^login\$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/login [R=301,L]
```

Where you replace `login` with `checkout.php` or whatever URL you need to support HTTPS on.

I'd argue this is a bad idea though. For the reasoning [please read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105510/force-https-for-specific-url/9105894#9105894).

Comment: This solution doesn't work when some pages (like login or sign up) use https protocol.

Comment: I've updated the post slightly to include some info. It's hard to both generically and correctly choose the protocol to use.

Comment: The first solution doesn't redirect enough, the 2nd seems to  redirect too much. For example `blog.example.com` becomes `www.blog.example.com`

Comment: Could you please also add how to avoid the redirect while developing on localhost?

Comment: ive been following everything on here but nothing is working. Im using a laravel setup. Does anyone have any idea why this isnt working for me? www.domain.com and domain.com both load properly but domain.com doesnt redirect to www.domain.com. Could this be a problem with my DNS?

Comment: Could be? what do you have in your DNS? I typically make www a cname that points to the A record of domain.com -- also I notice typos are pretty common with these bugs.

Comment: Thank you .. First solution is simple and efficient

Comment: How can we set the same configuration for Spring boot applications? As we don't have any .htaccess file in it?

Comment: Why not use the [QSA flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)?

Answer (score 115):

Here's the correct solution which supports https and http:

```
# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

UPD.: for domains like `.co.uk`, replace

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

Comment: This is perfect, it also doesn't redirect subdomains to `www` like the other generic solutions do.

Comment: This is a best solution, works much better than the accepted answer, and takes care of HTTPS properly

Comment: Works perfectly! And in such few lines!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this wouldn't work for more than one dot. Examples: `yoursite.co.uk`

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

When I type domain.de it takes me to `https://domain.de`. But I want `https://www.domain.de`

Comment: @TrashyMcTrash, this is by design, I don't think it makes sense to prepend a 3rd level domain with "www". Usually it's used only for 2nd level ones.

Comment: @AlexeyKosov There are TLDs, where you can't set up a 2nd level domain, for example .au, .uk, .jp. I know it is easy to change the snippet accordingly, just noting this for people who will use it for one of those TLDs.

Comment: @AlexeyKosov This doesn't make sense to you? `www.domain.co.uk`

Comment: @reformed It does. I meant subdomains like static.domain.com. Those domains (.au, .uk, .jp) are exception.

Comment: I like this because it helps redirect `.co.ke`

Answer (score 88):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

***For Https***

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This solution is preferred to @ranman's as it will work for all domains thus minimizing human error either when you're implementing code for a new project or when you implement extra-domains to an existing project.

Comment: I prefer this solution, but why `^(.*)$` instead of `(.*)`?

Comment: this solution is better but i have edited mine to contain yours as well.

Comment: This is working for all domain its simple and effective! Thank you

Comment: you may follow RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: this is third ttime you save me ;) thank you

Answer (score 27):

The following example works on both **ssl** and **non-ssl** and is much faster as you  use just one rule to manage http and https

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

[Tested]

This will redirect

**http**

- http://example.com

to

- http://www.example.com

**https**

- https://example.com

to

- https://www.example.com

Comment: Very close to what I came up with. Supports more than one dot in the HTTP host too, for example "mysite.co.uk".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you using R=301 here? It will use 302 (moved temp.) by default if no code specified.

Comment: Works perfectly. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: it will also redirect blog.domain.com to www.blog.domain.com, which is not always desired

Answer (score 9):

Try this, I used it in many websites, it works perfectly

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bewebdeveloper.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 7):

I have tested all the above solutions but not working for me, i have tried to remove the http:// and won't redirect also removed the www it redirect well, so i get confused, specially i am running all my sites under https://

So i have combined some codes together and came up with perfect solution for both http:// and https:// and www and non-www.

```
# HTTPS forced
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this can help someone :)

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

URLs redirect tutorial can be found from here - [Redirect non-www to www & HTTP to HTTPS using .htaccess file](http://www.codexworld.com/redirect-non-www-to-www-http-to-https-using-htaccess-file/)

Answer (score 3):

This configuration worked for me in bitnami wordpress with SSL configured :

Added the below under  "RewriteEngine On" in file /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect your domain which is not started with WWW
It is not redirect your all sub domain.

It is useful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the top answer successfully redirects non-www to www (ex: **mysite.com -> www.mysite.com**), but doesn't take into account wildcard subdomains, which results in:

```
random.mysite.com -> www.random.mysite.com
```

Here's a solution with/without HTTPS

**HTTP**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**HTTP/HTTPS**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=protocol:https]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=protocol:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:protocol}://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

*note: I haven't tested https because I don't currently have a cert to test, but if someone can verify or optimize what I have that would be awesome.

Comment: What does the first $ do here: '^(.*)$'

Answer (score 1):

If possible, add this to the main Apache configuration file. It is a lighter-weight solution, less processing required.

```
<VirtualHost 64.65.66.67>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 64.65.66.67>
   ServerAdmin me@example.com
   ServerName www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example
   .
   .
   . etc
```

So, the separate `VirtualHost` for "example.com" captures those requests and then permanently redirects them to your main `VirtualHost`. So there's no REGEX parsing with every request, and your client browsers will cache the redirect so they'll never (or rarely) request the "wrong" url again, saving you on server load.

Note, the trailing slash in `Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/`.
Without it, a redirect from `example.com/asdf` would redirect to `http://www.example.comasdf` instead of `http://www.example.com/asdf`.

Answer (score 1):

## Two warnings

Avoid 301 and prefer modern 303 or 307 response status codes.

### Avoid 301

Think carefully if you really need the permanent redirect indicated as `[R=301]` because if you decide to change it later, then the previous visitors of the page will continue to see the page of the original redirection.

The permanent redirection information is frequently stored in the browser's cache and, in general, it is difficult to eliminate (reload the page do not solve the problem). Your website visitors will be stuck in the previous redirect "forever".

### Avoid 302 too

The new version of the HTTP protocol (v1.1) added two new response status codes that can be used instead of 302.

- `303` URL redirection but demanding to change the type of request to
  GET.
- `307` URL Redirection but demanding to keep the type of request as initially sent.

You can still use the code `302` (non-permanent redirection) although it is considered ambiguous. In any case, most browsers implement `302` in the same way the new `303` code instructs.

Comment: regarding your warning about 301, this will apply even if we are talking about the same domain name? not so sure how this will apply in this case ... redirecting all URL's from `http://example.com/testing` to `http://www.example.com/testing`. Could be a bad approach in long term? Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

Write in .htaccess :)

```
## Redirect from non-www to www (remove the two lines below to enable)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Same as other answers