# Redirect URL from non-www to www mobile issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I tried this solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22299685 to redirect from non-www to www, it works when I tried it on my PC, also I checked the server header and it works fine (301), but when I tried on my mobile phone (android Gingerbread) using Firefox and type in `example.com` but the result still `example.com` not `www.example.com` this should be not an issue since this is a **Server** Header.

I'm not using mobile redirect on the website, desktop version for every device.
I typed in the code correctly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I missed?

EDIT:
Shoud I use a "mobile version" .htaccess that I didn't know?
Any advice would be great.

Comment: Clear your browser cache on mobile device.

Comment: Of course I tried, even I reinstalled the browser, none of these works