# Change to www if not a subdomain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Plot:** I actually like www URL's but not when used with subdomain like `www.whatever.example.com` . First i was using two domains on my hosting account so I added a htaccess rewrite like below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Motive:** Now after sometime I realised that I need a subdomain also pointed to my hosting account. But I don't want a ugly subdomain like `www.whatever.example.com` but at the sametime I want to redirect `example.com` users to `www.example.com`.
I am unable to figure out how to do that. Anyone here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule to only target your main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Or else, to target any sub-URL down to 3 levels 'deep':

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have two of the example.com and example2.com , the second code, should I use.

Comment: If you want add `www` to both `example.com` and `example2.com` then use 2nd rule.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using .htaccess,
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Question is about adding `www` not removing `www`.

Comment: Adding www to domain but not to subdomains.