# Why is my .htaccess redirect url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am trying to change my url when someone visits my site so non-www redirects to www ...http://example.com to http://www.example.com

I have found this code

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

But when i add it to my .htaccess i get a error....is this the wrong code ?? How do i add this to my .htaccess with out getting a error?

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond    %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ / profile.php?username=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines to your .htaccess file;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Source:

- http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/
- [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

You can add that, just below `RewriteEngine On` :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Overrite your .htacess file with following code.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond    %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ / profile.php?username=$1
```

More understanding of .htaccess rules:
http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2014/02/htaccess-code-snippets-example.html

Comment: Ok ...do i need to have RewriteEngine on 2 times??

Comment: No, It must be single time