# Super slow GET request of domain

Tags: performance, magento, get, pagespeed

I am building a magento webshop, which i am now trying to speed optimise. Using gtmetrix, i now have a performance grade of 89% which i am happy about for the time being.

However, the speed of the webside is much too slow, and i have optimised the speed from 8 seconds or longer, to about 3-4 seconds. But this is still to slow, as i want the loading speed to be about 1-2 seconds.

So, using pingdom, i have concluded, that it is the domain GET request which is messing it all up, see below:

[image]

The http://www.vinas.dk/ has a load time of 2,8 seconds, and the http://vinas.dk has a load time of 1,22 seconnds, so a total of 4,02 for the two first GET requests. I have also experienced, that this could be more than 5 seconds.

The rest of the requests of the website (141 requests) takes about 1,5 seconds.

How do i reduce the extensive load time of the two first GET requests (http://www.vinas.dk/ and http://vinas.dk), so these will be below 500ms of loadtime?

Comment: Why does it need 1.22sec to redirect vinas.dk to www.vinas.dk ? If you do this redirection at the http server level (or htaccess) you could spare this 1.22sec. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read through this guide to [Magento Performance in Nutshell](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/magento-performance-nutshell-joseph-edmonds-magento-expert-developer)

You might also want to have a look at [AOE Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler)

Basically, the speed issues you are seeing are the time it takes your PHP server to take the request and then build the corresponding page to serve up as a response.

Unfortunately, Magento often is not the best when it comes to speed though there are generally lots of opportunities to improve things if you work through it carefully.