# Apache/htaccess redirect all to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I got the following .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What I want to do is redirect everything to https://www. 
I thought that my htaccess should do exactly that, what's my mistake?

Comment: The question was answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite conditions are contradictory and will stop execution of rule. You can use this single rule to do both `https` and add `www`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

This will create a 302 (temporary) redirect. You can also use

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

to create a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Comment: Hmm. Am I correct in assuming that using `[R=301,L,NE]` on the last line would yield a *301 Permanent* redirect? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct. I suggest `R=302` for easy testing of redirect, otherwise 302 is aggressively cached in browsers.

Comment: Actually this single rule does 2 redirects:  
`http://servername.ru -> https://www.servername.ru`
and  
`http://www.servername.ru -> https://www.servername.ru`

but it doesn't process the last one `https://servername.ru -> https://www.servername.ru`

Comment: No it does only one redirect, you may have some other directive causing 2 redirects.