# Redirect all requests to non-www https

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I've searched for a solution of my problem on SO but none of the answers worked for me.

This is what i want to achieve:

```
Redirect all

http://example.com -> https://example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

Basically i want that whatever form of the domain is accessed to be redirected to **non-WWW https** (https://example.com)

Comment: This issue has been asked before.
Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess

Comment: that's not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: same old problem: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: Not with my code, it's in your config or htaccess with other rules

Comment: it is the only code in the htaccess.

And here is what the header looks like now: 
`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request => 
Server => cloudflare-nginx
Date => Sun, 13 Sep 2015 18:29:47 GMT
Content-Type => text/html
Content-Length => 177
Connection => close`

Comment: Problem with cloudflare configuration ? As I said, I think it's a problem with the configration.