# non-www to www redirect htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I have a little problem and I don't know why is that.

I tried :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But no succes.

It redirect the website from : `http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com`
**but not from `http://domain.com/sample-page to http://www.domain.com/sample-page`**

Why?!

**Update :** I use HHVM 3.6.6 . This can be the reason?! And place for .htaccess is in httpd-app.conf (Bitnami HHVM)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Comment: It might be a duplicate, but that one was for the case where the questioner left out a trailing slash

Comment: There is no duplicate of Redirect non-www to www. Right now this code is active.  **RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]**

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

If you want to apply this redirection by default, you can add it in the default VirtualHost in the "installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf" file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app.example.com
  ServerAlias www.app.example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 ...

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName app.example.com
  ServerAlias www.app.example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 ...
```

Please note that you will need to restart Apache to apply the changes.

```
installdir/ctlscript.sh restart
```

You can learn more about how to configure Apache using this link.

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache

I hope it helps.

Jota