# Opencart domain redirect to www

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to redirect my opencart `(version 2.1.0.1)` based project non-www to www. This accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess) working fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.ae/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when i added the code in .htaccess (which is located in the root folder. ) www.example.ae/admin and SEO URL (www.example.com/category-name)  does not working. Can any one guide me how can i fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have probably deleted everything else in your .htaccess file. Please make sure it looks something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```