# Symfony3 .htaccess redirection to www

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, symfony

I would like to redirect the link : "domain.com" to "www.domain.com"
But I don't really understand how the .htaccess redirections work in Symfony. Did someone already do this redirection on symfony ?
Thank you !

Comment: .htaccess redirects aren't dependant on Symfony

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Comment: thanks it works ! and sorry for the duplicate