# Rewrite dynamic pages AND non-www to www (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok, so I have a page.php placed on www.example.com/test that I want to rewrite to **www.example.com/test/page/id**   ( from www.example.com/test/page.php?page=id )

I added this simple .htaccess and everything's fine so far

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule page/(.*)/ page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule page/(.*) page.php?page=$1
```

The thing though is that I also want to redirect **example.com/test/page/id** to **www.example.com/test/page/id**

Is this possible to do? I tried adding a RewriteCond but it messed it up more.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Comment: That post doesn't talk about dynamic pages...

Comment: It's 2 concepts. First always redirect your non www to www with a 301 then your dynamic rewrite will work as you mentioned it.

Comment: Yeah but if I put a rewrite cond in the beginning it will only do the dynamic redirect to non-www

Comment: @Sylwit aren't i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't paid attention to your question please try this, I've tested it, put this in exact same manner with `[L,R]` flag

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule page/(.*)/ page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule page/(.*) page.php?page=$1
```

Comment: same problem, when i enter example.com/test/page/id it redirects to www.example.com/page/id while i want it to redirect to **www.example.com/test/page/id**

Comment: first you have to decide whether you want to it to apply on test directory or root directory i can edit it for test directory because for test it will require three matching groups.

Comment: applying on the test directory sounds ok, what should i change? thanks in advance

Comment: made some changed to your code and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To redirect non www requests to www, add the following rule bellow RewriteEngine line in your htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ http://www%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: it sends me to www.example.com/test/page/id?page=id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule page/(.*)/ page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule page/(.*) page.php?page=$1
```

Comment: sends me to: www.example.com/page/id  
(as I said on the question the page.php is placed on www.example.com/test)

Comment: Sorry but looks like no one understand what you want. Can you edit your question to be more explicit please.

Comment: Everyone who gave an answer was looking for the same solution, so if everyone failed, maybe it's because question in unclear

Comment: if you think so.. have a nice day