# rewrite from none www to www does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a website. A part of the website is wordpress the other part is without a CMS. I use the following .htaccess for my website. But the URLs which came from the "none cms-part" ( which have the slug /expose/ID ) of the website are accessible with and without www. When i use a rewrite Cond rule i get a 500 Servererror

i used the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.de$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain/$1 [R=permanent]
```

And here is my complete htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule ^unternehmen-2-2/?$ /unternehmen [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^expose/(.*)/$ content/index.php?content=expose&query=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I Hope somebody can help me that the urls with the slug /expose/id are only accessible with www

Comment: please search first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess

Comment: when i use the code from the other post i also get a 500 error. On which place i have to put the code in my htaccess?

Comment: no ideas? When i use this code RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] i alos get a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.This is working on my site.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```