# Rewrite non-www URL to www .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've used the following rule to redirect a non-www domain to www domain ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In this case the domain is redirecting to the www domain. This is due to full URL inclusion in the rule.

But is there a way to rewrite the domain to www instead of redirecting? I've tried some methods and doesn't worked. Someone experienced the same issue?

Comment: what do you mean by rewriting if you do not want to use www don't use it simple it will still fetch the page.

Comment: In my case the website works only with non-www url, but I need to add www to the URL.

Comment: You are doing it in a wrong direction. You need to redirect www to non-www.