# Domain redirect to www

Tags: php, redirect, web

i just want to redirect my domain. actually my website is working so there is no problem but i just want that when someone enter the website without (www) PHP has to detect this and redirect to with (www) i hope you understand. Thank you in advance. I am sorry for my bad English by the way.

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache or something else please be specified

Comment: This is normally done by editing/creating a .htaccess file and putting a mod-rewrite rule in it.. That might look like this...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^superdupersite\.com(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.superdupersite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only because I can't paste this as a comment..
redirect non-www to WWW

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^superdupersite\.com(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.superdupersite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this that have been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess) - instead, vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using your hostings DNS records settings. If you are using a Linux based hosting you can also do it using a htaccess document. Inside your HTAccess document simply put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.your-domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://your-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Read more about this: https://www.chriswiegman.com/2011/09/how-to-properly-redirect-your-domain-with-or-without-www/

Comment: He's actually asking for the opposite, non-WWW redirect to WWW

Comment: Also, please don't answer questions like this that have been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess) - instead, vote to close as duplicate.