# nonwww to www WITH redirect using .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all request without www to www, but I also need to every redirect will end on index.php

**.htaccess file code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(_part) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Current url :
 http://example.com

Expected url: http://www.example.com

Please,anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Comment: add expected output that make clear to reader what actual url needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(_part) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```