# redirect domain name to www

Tags: mean-stack

i am doing one site(https://www.mazabhumirakshak.in).Below is my issue:when user enter only mazabhumirakshak.in in URL then entry should redirect directly to www.mazabhumirakshak.in in background.
I have created this site using Node,Mongo,express and Angular(MEAN stack).
Your help will be valuable for me.

Thanks,
Guru

Answer (score 1):

on your Webserver you can crate a file .htaccess and
insert the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L
```

Complete answer here

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12050652/7883023

Comment: @Traver...i am using AWS for hosting site.should i need to create .htaccess file in prod server?

Comment: You need to create the .htaccess file in the directory where your index.php or index.html is located. The directory where your domain is pointing.