# Redirect to a new domain using apache vhost configuration

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have an apache vhost configurations as below. I want all my requests from

**somedomain.com/loadproduct?product=dell-inspiron-15**

to be redirected to

**someotherdomain.com/dell-inspiron-15**.

Can I do this from vhost configuration? Note that I have query parameters in the url.

```
Listen 12567
NameVirtualHost *:12567

<VirtualHost *:12567>
    ServerName somedomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ??
</VirtualHost>
```

Any leads here is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (instead of `RewriteRule ??`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?loadproduct$ http://someotherdomain.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I didn't get what "external redirect from actual URL to pretty one" and "internal forward from pretty URL to actual one" mean here?

Comment: But why is this rewrite "someotherdomain.com/dell-inspiron-15 to somedomain.com/loadproduct?product=dell-inspiron-15" needed?

Comment: My someotherdomain is self sufficient to respond to query it receives. Can we chat?

Comment: Sorry for bugging you again and again. This worked fine, but I dont want to redirect to a new URL for all the products. I have a whitelist of products like 

1. dell-inspiron-15
2. dell-inspiron-16
3. dell-inspiron-17 
...

for which I want to redirect to the new URL, for other products I want to use the current path itself. 

For example:
somedomain.com/loadproduct?product=dell-inspiron-15 -> redirect to 
someotherdomain.com/dell-inspiron-15

somedomain.com/loadproduct?product=hp-15-abcd -> do not redirect 

How can I do this redirection selectively? Leads here is appreciated.

Comment: Logged another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547418/selectively-redirect-to-a-new-domain-using-apache-vhost-configuration with the requirement. Please check if you have some free time. Thanks!