# Fallback - redirect to a new domain using apache vhost configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, vhosts

This is a followup question on https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47547418

I wanted my requests from

**somedomain.com/loadproduct?product=dell-inspiron-15**

to be selectively redirected to

**someotherdomain.com/dell-inspiron-15**

but at the same time I want to make sure if something goes wrong with the new domain, users are still able to use old domain by adding /old in the url.

For example if users uses

**somedomain.com/old/loadproduct?product=dell-inspiron-15**

then they should not be redirected to **someotherdomain** but should be served through a valid url **somedomain.com/loadproduct?product=dell-inspiron-15**

but if they use

**somedomain.com/loadproduct?product=dell-inspiron-15**

they should be redirected.

Currently my vhost configuration looks like below. It redirects to someotherdomain for selected products but there is no fallback configuration.

```
Listen 12567
NameVirtualHost *:12567

<VirtualHost *:12567>
    ServerName somedomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=(Dell-Inspiron-15) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=(Dell-Inspiron-16) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=(Dell-Inspiron-17) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?loadproduct$ http://someotherdomain.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
</VirtualHost>
```

Any leads here is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your RewriteCond conditions and add one where it says not to accept /old/ in the path (URI).  So:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/old/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=(Dell-Inspiron-15) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=(Dell-Inspiron-16) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=(Dell-Inspiron-17) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?loadproduct$ http://someotherdomain.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

In the first line, no need to specify [AND], as it is implicit.  The `!` character negates the match.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this on a real Apache, but I am pretty sure it is ok.

Comment: But /old is not a valid url, it should redirect to a url without /old

Comment: In  your question you say if `/old/` is present, do not redirect.  So the line I added is to make sure the RewriteRule is not applied to a request that contains `/old/`.  I misunderstood the question or?

Comment: I tried changing question language a bit, can you please check now?

Comment: Actually what I meant was use old in the url as a marker for fallback.

Comment: I added 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=(ENGY) [NC,OR]

so as expected "?loadproduct=ENGY" => Should be redirected but I can see url with "?loadproduct=ENGYHyd" is also getting redirected. Any idea why? Is it doing a prefix match?