# redirect non www to www for any tld

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am facing an issue for my .htaccess redirect to www from non www
I like to redirect any tld domain like .com or .co.uk etc.
I am using the following solution, from this link [[Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess])

```
# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but it only redirect tld with .com/.net etc but can't figure out how to change this so that it can grab any tld like .co.uk or .co.in etc.

EDIT: I have sub-domain there as well so using following rule not gonna work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for subdomain:

```
# rule for forcing www on main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rule for removing www on sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your suggestion. I forgot to say that I have tried this solution as well before but I have sub-domain there. So this solution makes my sub-domain no accessible.
N.B. I am gonna edit my question so that others don't misunderstand me.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(?:com|co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

If you have Apache 2.4+ then you can use `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(?:com|co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Hi buddy!
Thanks for your help, I am sorry that I forgot to mention that I have sud-domain for those domains as well, so this rule makes those sub-domain inaccessible. Can you help with that, please?
Thanks.

Comment: What are all top level you need to support? I guess `.com` and `.co.uk`, anything else?

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Let me explain a bit more about my scenario. I built an application where a user can register them and add their domain so that they will get the login page when they go to their domain. Now I would like to force www with all the domain. In this case I am not sure what would be the TLD. So I like to grab any TLD either with 3 letter or 2 and 3 letter or any combination. I hope you got my point.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, users cannot just create any domain with any TLD. At the most users can create a subdomain of an existing domain that you own. e.g. if you have `example.com` registered then your users may be able to create `user1.example.com`, `user2.example.com` etc but they cannot create `user1.anything.co.jp`, hope you understand this.

Comment: I am not sure why you say so. But the fact is I built the system and user can create their account and create a page. After that they add their domain in admin panel and add an A record to their domain to my server IP so that when they go to their domain it shows the page created by my application. It all works now and I use the following rule,
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
But it only grab TLD with single dot (ie, .com/.net/.org etc) but if they use other TLD like .co.uk, .co.in, .co.jp etc then it wont work. So what I need to change this rule something that can grap all TLD.

Comment: Ok but there is no regex pattern that I am aware of to differentiate *all* possible domains from all the subdomains.

Comment: Ohh thats unfortunate :(
Anyway thanks for your help :)