# CORS error when fetching api from its own domain

Tags: javascript, http, cors, fetch

One of app users constantly has an error when trying to fetch api from the same domain. This error occurs in Chrome only, other browsers are OK at his computer. He also tried to install Chrome CORS extention, but no luck. Does anybody has any idea why this might happen?

Error text below:

Failed to load http://my-app.com/api/v1/scoreboard: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.my-app.com' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: seems that www and no-www requests are not the same origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `www` and `non www` causing the problems of CORS. Then in my opinion you can set redirection of non WWW URL to WWW URL. It can be achieved using .htaccess or changing some settings on c-panel
Here the related answer [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Another option is to set cors headers on server side.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This depends on several things but usually calling code should not have any special configuration. instead your server side must decide to reject or allow the request. in case you can have a .htaccess file on your server side try to add this lines.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,PATCH"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,Authorization"
</IfModule>
```

Do not forget to add OPTIONS method in your allowed method list. Thats because the browser always checks the end-point availability by sending an OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 301 redirect from www to no-www domain name worked for me. Found solution here [Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)