# Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess causing internal error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to forward any non-www calls to www so I used answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) topic, but I get

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My code looks like this

```
AddDefaultCharSet utf-8

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]


RewriteRule ^team/(.*)/(.*)/$ team.php?t=$2 [L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @anubhava I got `RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters` error.

Comment: Code shown here worked fine on my Apache. I suspect some other rules may be present in your htaccess

Comment: @anubhava The other lines are below ^team line and look like them. nothing else

Comment: I cant guess because error is not happening for me. May be you have some control or hidden character somewhere.