# How to fix .js file url redirect to double WWW?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, web, url

When i try to access the resource on the browser like below

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5fu4.png)

It automaticly Became like this and causing error

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa8j5.png)

It is working fine without www. but i need to load the web with www.
Any advice?

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is working fine too for images and css files.. but not for js files

[Css Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKpBK.png)

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ts4S.png)

**UPDATE**

> looks like the problem only occured on a js file that has more than 1 dot.. 
>   for example https://www.testweb.com/js/bootstrap.js has 1 dot in bootstrap.js and it's working fine
>   but https://www.testweb.com/js/bootstrap.min.js has 2 dots.. and it caused double www
>   
> Any Clue?

Comment: Did you try adding in .env `APP_URL=http://www._your_domain` ?

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/12050590/5928015

Comment: Yes, already did it.. even i added URL::forceRootUrl(\Config::get('app.url')); to appservice provider..and take a look at description.. i added a new updates

Comment: @ViperTecPro sorry i tried that, but still not working.. .js file always redirect to double WWW

Comment: can you please tell how you are accessing css and js files with `asset('/path_to_css_or_js')` ??

Comment: No, just manually accesing it on browser.. like this..
www.testweb.com/js/bootstrap.min.js

i'm sorry i had to censored the url.. for privacy..

Comment: i added more update on description

Comment: \URL::forceScheme('https'); try adding in AppServiceProvider boot() method