# Laravel routes stopped working when accessing site with www

Tags: laravel, web, routes

I wanted my sites to use "www.", since I've read it is more SEO-friendly, therefore I have added the following code to my .htaccess file based on this answer [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess/36807965)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have two sites using the same project source (it's a content management system). One of them is working fine as it was, on the other one, all of the routes return 404. If I use a route without "www.", it works. How can I make my routes work when my page is fetched with "www."?

Current DNS setup (I've changed my actual domain with "mysite")

[image]

Comment: i think it handel by dns then your application

Comment: @KamleshPaul should I contact the host provider then?

Comment: no you need to create a DNS record name `www` value `@`

Comment: I've added my current DNS setup, could you provide an example wheat exactly I should add?

Comment: That is already there :/