# The requested URL could not be retrieved while trying to access Laravel project on Virtual Host with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I want to create a virtual host for my Laravel project with XAMPP, so I have followed these steps:

**Step 1)** `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\` Opened the "hosts" file (as Administrator):

```
127.0.0.1       test.com
```

**Step 2)** `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/freedeliveries/public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/freedeliveries/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
    ServerName www.test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 3)** `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. Scrolled down to the *Supplemental configuration* section at the end, and located the following section (around line 500), Removed the `#` from the beginning of the second line so the section now looks like this:

```
#Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**Step 4)** Restarted XAMPP and now run this in my browser :

```
www.test.com
```

But now I get this as result:

> **ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved**

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://test.com/

Unable to determine IP address from hostname test.com

The DNS server returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is root.
```

So how to solve this and ran the Laravel project on a virtual hostname?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: your project is developed in wordpress or core php or laravel ?

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad Laravel 5.8

Comment: http://localhost/freedeliveries/      is your project run directly with this url ?

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad I didn't understand your question. My project directory is placed at `xampp\htdocs\` and is called `freedeliveries`. Because it's a Laravel project I have to run CMD and type `php artiasn serve` and goto `localhost:8000` on browser to load the project. Now I need to load it by saying: `www.test.com` on browser.

Comment: is there any problem in my answer ?

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad Today when I wanted to start APACHE module on XAMPP, I get an error. I just added an **UPDATE** about it at the question

Comment: this is another problem which is not related to already asked question you have to ask another question for proper help .

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad Hey dude, I'm having similar issue, please would you mind checkout my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554478/laravel-virtual-host-on-xampp-does-not-work-properly

Comment: now in one question have  two questions for solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support subdomains in your project, you would need a DNS service. you can simply go with [Acrylic DNS Service](https://mayakron.altervista.org/support/acrylic/Home.htm), the configuration setup is [here](https://mayakron.altervista.org/support/acrylic/Configuration.htm).

**If using Acrylic DNS service**

1. Go to Acrylic UI
2. Open Acrylic Host from File>Open Acrylic Hosts
3. Place `127.0.0.1 *.test.com test.com` at the bottom of the host file
4. Restart the DNS service from Actions>Restart Aclyic Service
5. Place `127.0.0.1 test.com` in your windows host file

You may also setup your vhost file supporting the domain in `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost test.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/freedeliveries/public"
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias *.test.com
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/freedeliveries/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Simply add this routing to your `.htaccess` file in `/public folder`. Credits to @randall adding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12050652/7964905)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**If not using a DNS service**

If you want [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) only you could simply specify the host in your windows host file as `127.0.0.1 www.test.com` as @rakesh has shown and follow the steps.

Comment: Hey dude, I'm having similar issue, please would you mind checkout my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554478/laravel-virtual-host-on-xampp-does-not-work-properly

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps you will get your solution**

*1. Creating local domain for your project:*

so you need to modify the hosts file of Windows located in

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Then add the host using a custom host on your system, in this case we will add the `127.0.0.2` host that will be accesible as well with an alias of “`www.test.com`”.

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1 localhost
127.0.0.2 www.test.com
```

*2. Configure Virtual Host*
The entry point of a laravel application is the index.php inside the public folder, so the desired directory for our application will be the absolute path to your project in the public folder as shown in the following example.
The virtual host needs to point out the same host declared in the hosts file of windows (in this case 127.0.0.2) at the port 80. You can create this virtual host appending the following snippet at the end of the content of the httpd-vhosts.conffile located in the

`xampp folder \xampp\apache\conf\extra`

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
 DocumentRoot “C:/xampp/htdocs/freedeliveries/public”
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 ServerName www.test.com
 <Directory “C:/xampp/htdocs/freedeliveries/public”>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride all
 Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from all
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

*3. Open your project from the browser*
Finally as expected, by visiting either `www.test.com` or `127.0.0.2` in your browser will show the entry point of your Laravel application:

For More Details Follow this [URL](https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/configure-a-virtual-host-for-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows-10-d3f0068e7e1b) .

**port in use problem solution**

Disable the FTP Server that is already running (most likely running via Windows Add/Remove Programs -> Windows Features). Otherwise, you will need to change the port in the FileZilla settings located at %APPDATA%/FileZilla

Comment: I tried these steps but still cannot start Apache: https://themeisle.com/blog/xampp-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly/